# display non english character in textbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

i want to display some non english characters in a textbox.

i am trying with

```
$("#txtSearch").val('<%:Html.Raw(ViewBag.my_search)%>')
```

It should display '2100 - København Ø' but it is displaying '2100 - KÃ¸benhavn Ã˜'.

my controller reading this value from cookie and assigning it in a ViewBag. In the controller i have

```
ViewBag.my_search = cookie.Value 
// here it is assigning the right danish word but when it displays inside the input  box, it just displays wrong.
```

any idea how to solve this??

**EDIT:**

Well, it is working good in my local pc, but when I host it into some remote hosting provider, it does not perform good.

Comment: Are you declaring UTF-8 encoding on your page? Are you using it to store and encode your source data as well?

Comment: this is what i have in the view: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: The data you stored must use UTF-8 encoding as well. If this came from MS-Word it will need to be re-saved since the default encoding is Windows 1251, not UTF-8.

Comment: did you mean when I save data into cookie, I should use UTF-8 encoding at the time of saving?? how to do that? this is how i am saving data into cookie: public static void SaveToCookie(string name, string value)
        {
            HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
            _cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(_cookie);
        }

Comment: Wherever the data for "ViewBag.my_search" came from originally needs to be UTF-8. I guess that means when it was entered into your database.

Answer (score 1):

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` is not a good way to set your page's encoding because it is overriden by the real http header. So if the remote hosting provider is sending a content-type header, it will be ignored.

Your data is correctly utf-8, so that's good. All you need do is set the content-type http header, so that the browser will read it as utf-8 and not windows-1252.

You can set your individual page to send the header with:

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Or you can set it in Web.config globally:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you got a reference for headers overriding meta tags? I'd have thought it should be the other way around (the page itself should know more about its content than the server does) so want to confirm and see if there is a good reason for it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense now. My search-fu failed me in finding it myself. :)