# jQuery autocomplete ajax request not displaying returned data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I see on the debug developer tool ajax request responded with data but the data is not rendered in the text box. The data contains some special characters as you can see in the picture.

What is exactly wrong with the response function ? What (like utf-8 encoding maybe) should I add to the ajax call to display the special character ?

[image]

html:

```
<select name="selCat">
    <option>....</option>
</select>

<input class="col-3" type="text" id="txtPOI" name="txtPOI" />
```

jquery:

```
$("#txtPOI").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url("crowd/get_POIs") ?>',
                data: {cat: selectedCode, q: request.term},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                },
                fail : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                },minLength: 3
            });
        }
    });
```

Controller :

```
function get_POIs(){
        $cat = $this->input->post('cat');
        $q = $this->input->post('q');
        //echo $cat;

        if (isset($cat) && isset($q)){
            $cat = strtolower($cat);
            $q = strtolower($q);
            $data=$this->crowd->get_POIs($cat,$q);
            //echo "aa";
            $a_json = array();
            if(count($data) > 0){
                foreach ($data as $row){
                      $a_json_row["title"] = $row->title;
                      $a_json_row["contentid"] = $row->contentid;
                      $a_json_row["latitude"] = $row->latitude;
                      $a_json_row["longitude"] = $row->longitude;
                      array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);

                }
                echo json_encode($a_json);
            }   
        }

    }
```

Model :

```
function get_POIs($cat, $q){

    $this->db->DISTINCT();
    $this->db->select('title, a.contentid, latitude, longitude, address');
    $this->db->from('attraction a');
    $this->db->join('geographicdata g', 'a.contentid = g.contentid', 'left');
    $this->db->where('cat3 = "'.$cat.'"');
    $this->db->where('title like "%'.$q.'%"');
    $this->db->order_by('title','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    //die(var_dump($query));
    //echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Which autocomplete library are you using? Are you declaring which property on the returned objects to use as a label?

Comment: it's jquery ui autocomplete. As you can see in the jquery codes i just rendered the json data (contains values and labels)

Comment: @PriskaAprilia : What contains the js `response` function?

Comment: isn't it ajax response ?

Comment: @PriskaAprilia : You have to do something like that : `$('#div').html(data);`

Comment: try die(var_dump($query)); after $query = $this->db->get()->result(); see if any result is returned or not and also in controller and post result to examine

Comment: as shown in the image. there is a result.

Comment: I suggest to avoid mixing php in javascript sources everytime you can.
You can get the current page (or website root) URL using client-side javascript too.

Comment: add response data to your answer! and check, the success event will fired or not!

Comment: Did you check whether your browser has those type of characters enabled? (as in UTF-8) This might be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746703/display-non-english-character-in-textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by modifying the code inside the `success` event. Here how I did it.

change from

```
success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
```

to

```
success: function(data) {

            response( $.map( data, function( item )
            {
                return{
                        label: item.title,
                        value: item.title,
                        contentid: item.contentid,
                        latitude: item.latitude,
                        longitude: item.longitude
                    }
            }));

 }
```